# What is "BORING SSL" error which occurs during JSON using swift 4?

Tags: json, compiler-errors, xcode9, swift4, boringssl

The error is being displayed after JSON decoding. I saw this error in other posts too but they were related to Firebase and then Firebase fixed it with an update. My JSON is getting data from an website API.

Here is the error:

> [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_context_get_peer_sct_list: line 1754 received sct extension length is less than sct data length